# Laravel migration shows column doesn't exist for existing columns

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, database-migration

```
$users=DB::select('SELECT 
      users.id,
      users.name,
      course.id,
      course."courseUniqueName",
      skills.id,
      skills.skill,
      subjects.id,
      subjects.subject
       FROM users 
        LEFT JOIN course ON course."userId"=users.id
        LEFT JOIN skills ON skills."userId"=users.id
        LEFT JOIN subjects ON subjects."userId"= users.id');
```

I've written the above code in the up method of my migration but when running migrate command, it shows -

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 
SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column course.userid does not exist at character 294
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "course.userId".
```

**Course table migration file**

```
Schema::create('course', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->bigInteger('userId')->unsigned();
                $table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('users');
                $table->string('courseDisplayName');
                $table->string('courseUniqueName')->unique();
                $table->string('courseAddedBy');
                $table->dateTime('createdOn');
                $table->dateTime('lastUpdated');
                $table->softDeletes();        
            });
```

I don't have any idea why this error occurs because i've the `userId` column in my 'course` table migration. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Output:

```
"id": 1,
 "name": "weeee",
 "courseUniqueName": "Frehers course",
 "skill": "swim",
 "subject": "IELTS"
```

**View Query**

```
DB::statement("
      CREATE VIEW course_market_view AS
      (
        SELECT 
          users.id as user_id,
          users.name,
          course.id as course_id,
          course.courseUniqueName,
          skills.id as skill_id,
          skills.skill,
          subjects.id as subject_id,
          subjects.subject
           FROM users 
            LEFT JOIN course ON course.'userId'=users.id
            LEFT JOIN skills ON skills.'userId'=users.id
            LEFT JOIN subjects ON subjects.'userId'= users.id       
      )
    ");
```

**Model**

```
class CourseMarketView extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'course_market_view';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','name','course_id','courseUniqueName','skill','skill_id','subject_id','subject'];
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\CourseMarketView;

class CourseMarketController extends Controller
{
    public function getcoursebysubjectID(){

        $users = CourseMarketView::all();
        dd($users);
    }
}
```

Comment: @VahidMarali I didn't undertand what u said. What is alias? can u be more specific about how to define the alias?

Comment: my mistake sorry

Comment: @VahidMarali Why? wasn't ur answer relevant to my question?

Comment: sorry no it wasn't

Comment: I see "HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "course.userId". Can you try to change line: `LEFT JOIN course ON course."userId"=users.id` ?  Note `"` in  `course."userId"`

Comment: @AlexYu Then it shows syntax error. it look like this now. - `LEFT JOIN course ON course."userId"=users.id
 LEFT JOIN skills ON skills."userId"=users.id
LEFT JOIN subjects ON subjects."userId" = users.id`

Comment: Can you change outer quotes to single `'`  in `DB::Statement('` ?

Comment: @AlexYu Thanks. it works now. But it fetches only the data of the columns `id`, `name`,`coureseUniqueName`,`skill` & `subject`. it's not fetching the data from the columns `course.id`,`skills.id` & `subjects.id` .There is value for all thses columns in my db

Comment: @AlexYu I 've added the ouput am igetting now in the question body. pls see the updated question.

Comment: You're using wrong quotes here: `course."userId"=users.id` and similar places. You have to use backticks to wrap column names.

Comment: @Styx can u give a model of the suggestion u said? or can u post it as an answer

Comment: @Styx Look that query itself is in single quotes, so field names now correct

Comment: @user16467258 so the view now is correctly created, right? Can you update your question accordingly? About rows returned by view - I suppose that's an another question completely

Comment: Ah. I got it. See my answer

Comment: @AlexYu u r not posted any answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem A. "column course.userid does not exist"

With

> HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "course.userId"

This was solved by using `"` for field names with uppercased letters.

```php
$users=DB::select('SELECT 
      users.id,
      users.name,
      course.id,
      course."courseUniqueName",
      skills.id,
      skills.skill,
      subjects.id,
      subjects.subject
       FROM users 
        LEFT JOIN course ON course."userId"=users.id
        LEFT JOIN skills ON skills."userId"=users.id
        LEFT JOIN subjects ON subjects."userId"= users.id');
```

- Single quotes for query
- double quotes around fields names

## Problem B. `id`-fields

> it's not fetching the data from the columns course.id,skills.id & subjects.id

The problem is that 4 fields are named as `id`.

To fix it - use field aliases:

```php
$users=DB::select('SELECT 
      users.id as user_id, # note rename of the field here
      users.name,
      course.id as course_id, # and here
      course."courseUniqueName",
      skills.id as skill_id,  # and here
      skills.skill,
      subjects.id as subject_id,  # and here
      subjects.subject
       FROM users 
        LEFT JOIN course ON course."userId"=users.id
        LEFT JOIN skills ON skills."userId"=users.id
        LEFT JOIN subjects ON subjects."userId"= users.id');
```

This way `id` will became 4 different fields as it's in reality:

- `user_id` - from table `users`
- `course_id` - from `course`
- `skill_id` - from `skills`
- `subject_id` - from `subjects

Change application code accordingly to field renames.

Comment: But ther is one problem still. Am using this query in creating a view. there it shows complete syntax error when i've added the quotes like u said. Pls see the updated question

Comment: Change outer quotes to single and use double quotes around field names

Comment: althuough I created the view succesfully , My controller is not returning any data from the view. Pls see the code in my updated question body

Answer (score -1):

the HINT is saying itself. you dont have column `userid`

what you have in your table is `userId`

Comment: But what will i do to solve that? i'm using correctly `course.userId` in my query . But it is checking `course.userid`. What's the solution of that?